# Linux console control in windows like Putty

Tags: windows, console, putty

I was using Putty the other day and realized that it has it's own console control (a Linux one not the windows command prompt) and I was wondering how they did it? Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean how they implemented the terminal emulator specifically?  If it helps, the whole source for PuTTY is available to download here: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: It's not "a Linux console" - it's a terminal emulator. Terminals predate Linux by decades.

Comment: @Colin you should make your comment an answer so it can be accepted. Likewise @ExtremeCoder you should view the source and accept Colin's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: PuTTY does almost no "console" work; it just shows what it happening on the server, like a text-only remote desktop.

---

PuTTY has a number of different components; the most significant are the *backends* which implement communications over such things as SSH, Telnet, and serial ports, and the ***terminal emulator*** which is probably the bit you are interested in.

The work done by the terminal emulator is most easily understood by explaining a little about the history of terminals; back before I was born, in days of old movies, terminals were seriously limited devices - a keyboard and printer, capable of sending the keystrokes over a simple wire and printing characters (on paper!) when simple commands were sent back.  All the actual thinking was done by the room-sized mainframe at the other end of the wire.  Terminals later added simple video output to improve the user experience of global thermonuclear war:[image: terminal in wargames]

The information going over the wire to the video terminals were much the same, with a few extra commands added to make pretty colours and so on.

Eventually, around the time I was born, the dinosaurs die off and we enter the modern age of computers, and it becomes practical for normal mortals like us to have a *whole computer* to themselves, but mechanism for terminals was still around and too useful and reliable to throw away; so ***terminal emulators*** were invented; the same simple commands are sent up the wire, and terminal software fakes up the same display a video terminal would have shown.

If you wanted to go about writing one of these yourself, you would need:

1. [An understanding of the control sequences](http://vt100.net/emu/) of the type of terminal you want to emulate.
2. A programming environment with a *lot* of control; the text controls of most graphical toolkits won't cut it.
3. Patience
4. More patience.

These links might help if you take the plunge:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator
- http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/terminals.html
- [Programming a terminal emulator, what's in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535212/programming-a-terminal-emulator-whats-in-it)
- http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html