# What are the Windows Registry shell command percent codes?

Tags: windows, syntax, registry, command-line-arguments, contextmenu

I've seen various percent codes in use as a place-holder for the selected file/folder:

- [`%L`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26878374/5306507)
- [`%V`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902253/5306507)
- [`%1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21370381/5306507)

How do these differ?

A link to documentation would be nice too.

Comment: [Which special variables are available when writing a shell command for a context menu](https://superuser.com/q/136838/604278) answers the question.